# .NET Prism + MEF Get All Instances of Type

Tags: .net, prism, mef

I'm working on a modular application with Prism 5.0 and MEF and I'm having a hard time getting all the instances created in the application of a Generic Interface.

I have a generic **`IDataService<T>`** Interface

```
 public interface IDataService<T>
 {
    ...
 }
```

I then have a base class  **`DataServiceBase<T>`** that implements this Generic Interface.

```
public abstract class DataServiceBase<T> : IDataService<T>
{
    ...
}
```

And an Implementation of the Base Class **`DataService<T>`**

```
[Export(typeof(IDataService<>))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public sealed class DataService<T> : DataServiceBase<T> 
{
    ...
}
```

The other classes get the specific dependency injected into the constructor like this:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public SubmenuViewModel(IDataService<SubmenuItemModel> dataService)
{
    ...
}
```

When the application is closing i want to retrieve all the instances created of **`IDataService<T>`** and call the **`Save()`** method on them. I've tried a couple of different things but I get an empty array or 1 instance which i believe it's a new instance not an existing one.

```
// This returns an empty array.
var d = this.Container.GetExports(typeof(IDataService<>), null, null); 
// This return 1 instance.
var z = this.Container.GetExports(typeof(IDataService<object>), null, null);
```

I've also tried creating a base Interface **`IDataService`**, and having **`IDataService<T>`** inherit from it. Then Exporting the **`DataService<T>`** as both **`IDataService`** and **`IDataService<T>`** without any success either.

```
var z = this.Container.GetExports(typeof(IDataService), null, null);
```

Is this even possible or should I have a class that keeps track of the instances?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What result are you getting when exporting the `DataService<T>` as `IDataService`?

Comment: Nothing, empty array.

Comment: Normally, this should work. `GetExports(Type, null, null)` should return all the exports of given type with default contract name (that means, registered as `[Export(Type)]`). Have you tried to inspect your container with debugger? Are there any exports just before you call the `GetExports()` method?